# Java Client Server Socket related problem

Tags: java, client-server, bufferedreader

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        String ip = "localhost";
        int port = 5643;
        Socket s = new Socket(ip, port);
        String str = "Sagar Tanwar";
        OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os);
        os.write(str);
        os.flush();
    }
}
```

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        System.out.println("Server is started");
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5643);
        
        System.out.println("Server is waiting");
        Socket s = ss.accept();
        
        System.out.println("Client Connected");
        
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        String str = br.readLine();
        
        System.out.println("Client Data : "+str);
    }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:555)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:451)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:228)
```

Comment: maybe check your firewall?

Comment: if i used ip address instead of "localhost" then i got this exception    Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)

Comment: Can you [edit] your question, and give a little more background on your environment.  Personal Laptop?  Accessing same laptop?  Corporate environment?  Accessing different server?  In same network, or over the public internet?

Comment: Either your server wasn't running at all or it wasn't running in the client host. NB As usual. You are reading lines but you aren't writing lines. Try `write(str+"\n")`.

Comment: @SomerandomITboy Firewalls don't cause connection refusals. They cause connection timeouts. In any case the OP is using `localhost`, which suggests at best a LAN.

Answer (score 2):

In `Client.java` change this line:

```
String str = "Sagar Tanwar";
```

to:

```
String str = "Sagar Tanwar\r\n";
```

---

Your server expects to read a *full line* (`br.readLine()`) and it continues to read until your client stays connected. Once the client disconnects, an exception is thrown because the server was unable to read a new line.

#### Side notes

On my system:

- your client throws: `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect` - if the server is not active
- your server throws: `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset` - if the server can't read a full line from the client

Comment: "Once the client disconnects, an exception is thrown": false. `readLine()` returns `null`, rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: @user207421 I've **ran** the OP's code. First the server, then the client. The client has sent over its string and exited normally. The server has terminated with `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset` while performing `br.readLine();`. I'm not sure I follow you.

Answer (score -1):

Everything will work for you if you close the connections at the end of the client class.

```
    String ip = "localhost";
    int port = 5643;
    Socket s = new Socket(ip, port);
    String str = "Sagar Tanwar";
    OutputStreamWriter os = null;
    try {
        os = new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        os.write(str);
        os.flush();
    } finally {
        if (os != null)
            os.close();
    }
```

or with "try with resources"

```
    String ip = "localhost";
    int port = 5643;
    Socket s = new Socket(ip, port);
    String str = "Sagar Tanwar";
    try (OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream())) {
        os.write(str);
        os.flush();
    }
```

Comment: I still got the same error after close the connections at the end of client class.

Comment: You need to start the server first and then only to client

Comment: He doesn't have a connection to close yet. Read the question.

Answer (score -4):

```
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String ip = "localhost";
        int port = 5643;
        Socket s = new Socket(ip, port);
        String str = "Sagar Tanwar";
        OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os);
        os.write(str);
        os.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: The difference being? which solves the problem how? and the problem was? Mere code is not an answer.